# how to create an event hub listener?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

How do I create an event hub listener in Azure?  The following video is a good intro to Azure event hub creation and wireup with logging:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs/

I've gotten to the part where the presenter shows an Azure event hub listener running in a console app:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9BQiDEzshCza3NVTUV2XzExTFk/view?usp=sharing

However, the presenter didn't walk through the creation of the Azure event hub listener and I googled it and didn't find any references. Can you explain how to create an event hub listener in Azure?

Comment: One of my plans is to take my ApimEventProcessor and deploy it as a WebJob, but I haven't got round to it yet https://github.com/darrelmiller/ApimEventProcessor/tree/master/src/ApimEventProcessor

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a normal Event Hub listener you can refer to its documentation on how to listen for events: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/